# App crashes when trying to resign keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Since I updated to the latest Xcode 6 beta, I have been having issues with closing the keyboard. My app is crashing each time I try to close the keyboard, even though I have used the same code for ages and it used to work fine.

Here is what I have:

```
@IBAction func viewTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
    //Closes keyboard when user touches screen.

    transactionDateInput.resignFirstResponder()
    transactionNameInput.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    notesField.resignFirstResponder()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
        self.valueEnter.alpha = 0
        self.dateEnter.alpha = 0
        self.notesDone.alpha = 0
        })
}
```

Someone suggested changing it to something like this:

```
if (transactionDateInput.isFirstResponder() == true){
     transactionDateInput.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

but that makes no difference. Anyone have any suggestions? Here is the error:

```
AffordIt[4445:1334424] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AffordIt.SecondViewController textFieldShouldReturn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb169666880'
```

Comment: What's the error message you are getting when the app crashed ?

Comment: I've updated my question with the error.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error message. Have you implemented the method textFieldShouldReturn in SecondViewConvtoller?

Comment: I don't have the beta installed, but is textFieldShouldReturn still an optional on the UITextFieldDelegate protocol in the 8.3 SDK?  It would surprise me, but that's what this error sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Text Field outlet delegate (right click to Text Field)
there should be delegate to your UIViewController!

Look at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT-P2kJr45A)